# eclipse + jython: importError: No module named pycurl

Tags: python, eclipse, jython

I know this Error is known and there are a few solutions, but none worked for me.

I work with eclipse neon + jython 2.7 on a Mac. NO virtualenv.

I want to import pycurl, which is correctly installed!

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

The PythonPath in Eclipse is set to site-packages and pycurl and so on. i already tried every combination! 
I restarted eclipse every time after changing something at the paths.

I tried different installations:

```
sudo -H pip install pycurl
easy_install pycurl
pip -v install pycurl
pip -v install pycurl --upgrade
```

But if it is installed with one of these methods. it will always say that its already installed, when trying to install via another command. 
So I deinstalled and installed multiple times. I even tried it with the download of the pycurl website

So any suggestions, how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much to do with pyCurl, but I try a guess.

Is pyCurl implemented as a ".so"?
If yes: It won't work, because Jython can't deal with it, because it's C-Stuff. Jython can only use pure Python or Java modules.

In that case you have to look for an alternative in Java/Python or you need to find/create a wrapper and use JNI.

If no: Did you add pyCurl in your project source folder the right way?
Did you "import" in your code the right way?

Comment: Yes it ist implemented as a .so :/